# Написание функций в Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

Пишу на C++. Можно ли настроить Visual Studio так, чтобы при автоматическом завершении функции писались две скобки?

```
MyFunc()
```

Просто сейчас при автозавершении функции пишется просто её имя `MyFunc`

Answer (score 0):

1. откройте окно настроек Main Menu → Tools → Options
2. на вкладке Text Editor → C/C++ → General выставите галочку Automatic brace completion
3. на вкладке Text Editor → C/C++ → Advanced убедитесь, что левая круглая скобка присутствует в списке Member List Commit Characters

После этих манипуляций при автодополнении функции левой круглой скобкой сразу будет появляться и правая. Это работает и для [] {} <>.

Comment: вот только автор вопроса похоже хочет немного другого. Он хочет, что бы когда с списка автодополнения выбрал свою функцию, к ее имени сразу добавлялись и скобки.

Comment: Оно так и будет работать.

Comment: нет. В указанных Вами настройках нужно ручками поставить открывающую скобку и только потом оно добавил закрывающую. А автор хочет что бы обе скобки сразу стали.

Comment: Не понимаю, что вам не нравится. Конечный результат же оказывается нужным - при автоматическом завершении после имени оказываются две скобки.

Comment: я пробовал. Не работает так. Нужно добавлять открывающую скобку ручками

Comment: Не понимаю, вы что, хотите, чтобы скобки подставлялись при завершении актокомита по нажатию на Enter появлялись? Конопку завершения атодополнения придется нажимать в любом случае, а так можно сразу выбрать пару скобок, которая появится после функции или другого символа. После функции кстати иногда может быть удобно вместо круглых скобок угловые поставить.

Comment: не я, а автор вопроса так хочет. Я то понимаю, что они после функции часто и не нужны. Перечитайте вопрос ещё раз

Comment: Тут при автоматическом завершении функции будут появляться круглые скобки. Как раз то, что хочет автор вопроса. О том, что автоматическое завершение должно быть именно по Enter - в вопросе ни сказано ни слова.

Comment: я думаю, что тут ещё какой то плагин. Я как не изголялся с автоматическим завершением, скобки не появляются сразу.

Comment: Не, это вроде из коробки должно работать.

Comment: вот сейчас пишу несколько букв с имени функции, жму ctrl+Space, в подсказках вижу свою функцию, нажимаю на нее мышкой, жму tab - имя дописывается, но скобочек нет. Нажимаю открывающую скобку - сразу появляется и вторая.

Comment: Когда функция в списке выбрана, то *вместо* таба можно сразу нажимать открывающую скобку. После этого должно сразу и имя дописаться, и обе скобки появиться.

Comment: не работает. если нажимать нажимать скобку, то оно добавляет скобку, а имя не дописывает

Comment: ¿Хм, а это только скобка в этом случае не работает, или все остальные символы, перечисленные в Member List Commit Characters тоже?

Comment: не имеет значения. я по разному пробовал

Comment: Ну тут я даже не знаю, что сказать. У меня студия почти без плагинов и они все работают.